# Error while using tensorflow's tf_agents.environments.ParallelPyEnvironment with standard gym environments, hitting recursive limit

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to initiate parallel environments for multiprocessing. Although I am using a custom environment, I get the same error with standard gym environment.

This is the minimal example code that is showing the same error as my custom environment.

```
env1 = suite_gym.load("Taxi-v3")
def GetmyENV():
  return env1
parallel_py_env = ParallelPyEnvironment([GetmyENV]*int(4))
```

This is the error:

```
E0611 20:43:09.540677 140416971974464 parallel_py_environment.py:492] Error in environment process: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/parallel_py_environment.py", line 458, in _worker
    env = cloudpickle.loads(self._pickled_env_constructor)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/wrappers.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._env, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/wrappers.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._env, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/wrappers.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._env, name)
  [Previous line repeated 941 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-7a1314b24b78> in <cell line: 8>()
      6   return env1
      7   # tf_env=tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(parallel_py_environment.ParallelPyEnvironment([get_Snake_Env]*int(n_envs)))
----> 8 parallel_py_env = ParallelPyEnvironment([GetmyENV]*int(200))

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/parallel_py_environment.py in wait_start(self)
    282       self._process.join(5)
    283       raise result
--> 284     assert result == self._READY, result
    285 
    286   def observation_spec(self) -> types.NestedArraySpec:

AssertionError: (5, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/parallel_py_environment.py", line 458, in _worker\n    env = cloudpickle.loads(self._pickled_env_constructor)()\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/wrappers.py", line 55, in __getattr__\n    return getattr(self._env, name)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/wrappers.py", line 55, in __getattr__\n    return getattr(self._env, name)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_agents/environments/wrappers.py", line 55, in __getattr__\n    return getattr(self._env, name)\n  [Previous line repeated 941 more times]\nRecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded\n')
  In call to configurable 'ParallelPyEnvironment' (<class 'tf_agents.environments.parallel_py_environment.ParallelPyEnvironment'>)
```